# Azure Databricks Cluster API Authentication

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have a spark cluster on Azure DataBricks and I am trying to access Cluster Information via this Rest API https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/clusters.html#get.

However, I am unable to figure out the correct way of using the personal token to authenticate.

Here are the possible combinations that I have tried and their result

1. Encoding the personal token in base 64 format "Token:[personal token]"

[image]

2. Using the personal token as it is
   [image]
3. Using token id available from User Settings Screen

[image]

In all the cases, I am getting 401 Error.
Can someone please help in finding the correct way of using the token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Token that you get is Bearer token so it would be as

```
Authorization: Bearer <token_here>
```

And with CURL

```
curl 'https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/clusters/get?cluster_id=<id>' -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <personal-access-token-value>"
```

There is no need for encoding or anything. It's already encoded.

Comment: And if I using the Apache Spark API, not the Databricks API, how authentication would work: `curl 'https://<databricks-instance>/api/v1/applications' -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <personal-access-token-value>"` ?